# Get raw voice recording from android's search framework

Tags: java, android, search, voice-recognition

I'm planning to use [Android's Search Framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) with voice recognition to

- Search thru existing texts (Short sentences of 5-10 words) by typing or by voice
- If search was by voice, I'd like store the search itself (the search text) but also the raw sound, that was recorded.

Looking at the guide and into everything written about this, **I cannot find a way to get the raw recorded voice, nor can I find something where I can provide a recorded sound to the search interface.**

Does anybody know, if this is at all possible? And if not, is there any other way to get the search query AND the recorded voice? Maybe by recording one voice into two activities?

I know how to record voice, how to play it and how to let the user search using the search framework. It's the combination of a user speaking one time into the microphone and getting that sound AND use it for searching.

Any link, further reading or keyword to search for, would be helpful.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip

Comment: I searched like hell and didn't find it. The answers in (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319735/voice-recognition-on-android-with-recorded-sound-clip) look really promissing. Thanks @nikolay-shmyrev

Comment: Another one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583406/saving-audio-input-of-android-stock-speech-recognition-engine?rq=1